# Double Integral Question: How are the limits set up?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

[image]I am trying to find the area of the line y = x and below by the parabola $y = x^2-2x. $
I am using a double integral. However, for the integral, this is the correct answer:
$$ \int_0^3\int_{x^2-2x}^xxdydx $$

I don't understand how the dy limits of integration are set up? Isn't it right function-left function? The graph on the right is the $x^2-2x$. But in the limits of integration, this is reversed?

In the picture the blue graph is $x^2-2x$ and the red is $y=x$

Comment: Draw a picture. And there should be no "$(x)$" in the "correct answer".

Comment: @AnneBauval Got the picture and got rid of the brackets around the x

Comment: I know that your question was about the limits and not the integrand. However, again: (if you want the area) the integrand should be $1,$ not $x.$ Btw nice picture. I was just advising to draw it for yourself, for you to better understand the situation.

Comment: To find the area below the line $y=x$ and above the parabola $y=x^2-2x$, you'll set up the following integral:
$$\int_0^3\int_{x^2-2x}^x dy dx = \frac{9}{2}$$
The limits are in this way because $x^2-2x < y < x$ and $0 < x < 3$ i.e it's these inequalities that get you points inside the desired region